# Error creating SQL Server on Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

My configuration is as follows:

[image: Configuration]

Nothing is changed in the **advanced** section.

My error message:

[image: Error message]

What's wrong here?

Comment: Is a `localhost` name of your SQL Server Instance?

Comment: I don't know what a server instance is, sorry - please elaborate.

Comment: Open `cmd`, write `OSQL -L` - this will give you the value that needs to be put instead the `localhost`

Comment: @gotqn I'm on mac, that command doesnt work...

Comment: Hi @viruscube, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-ver15) is a cross-platform database tool for data professionals using the Microsoft family of on-premises and cloud data platforms on Windows, MacOS, and Linux.

It can not help you create the SQL Server.

About how to create the SQL server on MAC, please reference bellow tutorials:

1. [Install SQL Server 2019 on a Mac](https://database.guide/install-sql-server-2019-on-a-mac/)
2. [How to Install SQL Server on a Mac](https://database.guide/how-to-install-sql-server-on-a-mac/)

When the SQL Server created, you can using  Azure Data Studio to connect to it with Server name, user, password which set these details during install the SQL Server.

After then, you have the enough environment to connect to Azure SQL database.

Hope this helps.